# Get-DLPComplianceRule returns System.Collections.Hashtable

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am using Get-DLPComplianceRule and trying to read the parameter "ContentContainsSensitiveInformation" but i am getting "System.Collections.Hashtable" instead of the actual value stored. Below is the code snippet.

```
$jComplianceRule= Get-DLPComplianceRule -Policy "Finance Rule" | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host $jComplianceRule | ConvertFrom-Json

"ContentContainsSensitiveInformation":  [
{"groups":  "System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable",                                                    "operator":  "And"}]
```

,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert it to Json and use the following script to get the `ContentContainsSensitiveInformation` defined in the groups.

```
$jComplianceRule= Get-DLPComplianceRule -Policy "Finance Rule"

$SensitiveInformation = ""

foreach ($group in $jComplianceRule[0].ContentContainsSensitiveInformation[0].groups){
    $SensitiveInformation += $group.sensitivetypes | ConvertTo-Json
}

Write-Host $SensitiveInformation
```

Comment: Any idea how to go the reverse direction?  Use New-DlpComplianceRule and setup multiple groups?

Answer (score 0):

@codesniffer to setup multiple groups you can use like this.

```
-ContentContainsSensitiveInformation @{operator = "Or"; groups = @(@{name = "Group1"; operator = "And"; sensitivetypes = @(@{Name = "Rule1"; minconfidence = "80" ; minCount = "1" }, @{Name = "Rule2"; minconfidence = "85" ; minCount = "1" }) }; @{name = "Group2"; operator = "And"; sensitivetypes = @(@{Name = "Rule3"; minconfidence = "80" ; minCount = "1" }) }) }
```